# Switch on the id of check boxes in javascript don't work?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, switch-statement

```
function handleCheckBoxEvent(cb){               
        var index = 0;
        switch (cb.id){
            case "cb0":
                index = 0;
                alert(cb.id);
                break;
            case: "cb1":
                index = 1;
                alert(cb.id);
                break;
        }
}
```

And i call this when i check the box like the following:

```
<input id="cb0" type="checkbox" onclick="handleCheckBoxEvent(this);">Frist</label>
```

I can't figure out why the above switch doesn't work ?

Any help will be very appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: It didn't output any thing.
I think the problem in switch statement, cause when using if statement instead it works like:

if(cb.id == "cb0")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 function handleCheckBoxEvent(cb){               
    var index = 0;
    switch (cb.id){
        case "cb0":
            index = 0;
            alert(cb.id);
            break;
        case**:** "cb1":
            index = 1;
            alert(cb.id);
            break;
    }
}
```

You got an extra ":" in the second case, probaly remove it and i should be fine.

Tested it and after removing the unnessercary ":" it works.

Comment: ya that is, thanks. but is there any good IDE i can use which shows me these simple mistakes that i forget it, i just using Sublime, I want a real IDE for javascript and for debugging php?

Thanks.

Comment: I use Sublime aswell and for php there are phplint tools. I don't program to much in Javascript but there could be also. If you want a "real" IDE you could take Eclipse. I like this one and has a PHP version

Comment: You should also consider Firebug. Firebug was the one which pointed out the extra ":". You don't need Firebug but I like it. But most browser has build in web developers tools which show these kind of things.

Comment: Webstorm is a payed program though. Not it should stop you it looks amazing but the ones i mentioned are free :)

Comment: True, but it's quite inexpensive. Sublime isn't free either. Eclipse has a learning curve (and config curve!) that far outstrips the amount of money you save. I spent a couple hours trying to get a node js app to open in Eclipse without a cryptic error and gave up.

Comment: Yes you are right, but sublime text 2 can be used forever though. And the question is about PHP eclipse. Which i think is not so hard to config, because it is simply right click ;) About your issue with node js, yes I can see that :) Had some issues with similar things aswell. I prefer Sublime over Eclipse still.

Comment: @Grimm: good lord, paying for software. Heaven forfend anyone should do that.

Comment: I think I am giving the wrong expression back about paying for software. I do have paid software on my computer and all. What I'm saying here or meaning that i prefer sublime text 2 (nowadays 3) over all the other editors ( I tried many ) because I can code very fast in sublime (looking into bracket now, whichs looks awesome ). I think it is easy to understand and it doesn't get it my way. So I have nothing against paying for software =), as it gives the developers a way to make better programs, etc... I am merly saying that I prefer sublime over alot of editors. Thats it

Comment: But if a software package is free, it is a pro against a payed package which forfills the same needs as a payed one. As a student I have to weigh down and give my opinion on certain software package and the reason why I choose to use it in a context. Sometimes a free packages wins and sometimes a payed one. I think it comes down to, what do you need.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix your case statement, I went a different direction. It looks like you want to set a value based on the id of the control, so I added `data-index="0"`. The HTML5 data- attributes are really handy!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script> 
    handleCheckBoxEvent = function (cb){
      id =cb.getAttribute("data-index"); 
        console.log("ID is: " + id);                  
    }      
  </script>       
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>        
    <input id="cb0" data-index="0" type="checkbox" onclick="handleCheckBoxEvent(this);">Frist</label>
      </body>     
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ciiXktIfH7PGTiquHi7P